# How to pass react-native props from functional component to class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props, react-component

I am creating a music player for a streaming app and I want to make a dynamic playlist. I am using Expo AV and Firebase to store music and information.

I already have everything configured but I can't pass the "cancionesPlaylist" prop (which is already an array) from the parent functional component to the child class component. This is the code I have:

```
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, View, Image } from "react-native";
import { Title, Text } from "react-native-paper";
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";
import { Button } from "../components/Button";
import { Audio, Video } from "expo-av";
import firebase from "../utils/firebase";
import "firebase/firestore";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

export default function ReproductorAudio(props) {
  const { route } = props;
  const { canciones } = route.params;
  const cancionesPlaylist = canciones;

  return <ReproductorMusica cancionesPlaylist={cancionesPlaylist} />;
}

class ReproductorMusica extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const cancionesPlaylist = props.cancionesPlaylist;
    console.log(cancionesPlaylist);
  }

  state = {
    isPlaying: false,
    playbackInstance: null,
    currentIndex: 0,
    volume: 1.0,
    isBuffering: false,
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
        allowsRecordingIOS: false,
        interruptionModeIOS: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_IOS_DO_NOT_MIX,
        playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
        interruptionModeAndroid: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_ANDROID_DUCK_OTHERS,
        shouldDuckAndroid: true,
        staysActiveInBackground: true,
        playThroughEarpieceAndroid: true,
      });

      this.loadAudio();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  async loadAudio() {
    const { currentIndex, isPlaying, volume } = this.state;

    try {
      const playbackInstance = new Audio.Sound();
      const source = {
        uri: cancionesPlaylist[currentIndex].uri,
      };

      const status = {
        shouldPlay: isPlaying,
        volume,
      };

      playbackInstance.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(this.onPlaybackStatusUpdate);
      await playbackInstance.loadAsync(source, status, false);
      this.setState({ playbackInstance });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  onPlaybackStatusUpdate = (status) => {
    this.setState({
      isBuffering: status.isBuffering,
    });
  };

  handlePlayPause = async () => {
    const { isPlaying, playbackInstance } = this.state;
    isPlaying
      ? await playbackInstance.pauseAsync()
      : await playbackInstance.playAsync();

    this.setState({
      isPlaying: !isPlaying,
    });
  };

  handlePreviousTrack = async () => {
    let { playbackInstance, currentIndex } = this.state;
    if (playbackInstance) {
      await playbackInstance.unloadAsync();
      currentIndex < cancionesPlaylist.length - 1
        ? (currentIndex -= 1)
        : (currentIndex = 0);
      this.setState({
        currentIndex,
      });
      this.loadAudio();
    }
  };

  handleNextTrack = async () => {
    let { playbackInstance, currentIndex } = this.state;
    if (playbackInstance) {
      await playbackInstance.unloadAsync();
      currentIndex < cancionesPlaylist.length - 1
        ? (currentIndex += 1)
        : (currentIndex = 0);
      this.setState({
        currentIndex,
      });
      this.loadAudio();
    }
  };

  renderFileInfo() {
    const { playbackInstance, currentIndex } = this.state;
    return playbackInstance ? (
      <View style={styles.trackInfo}>
        <Text style={[styles.trackInfoText, styles.largeText]}>
          {cancionesPlaylist[currentIndex].name}
        </Text>
        <Text style={[styles.trackInfoText, styles.smallText]}>
          {cancionesPlaylist[currentIndex].author}
        </Text>
        <Text style={[styles.trackInfoText, styles.smallText]}>
          {cancionesPlaylist[currentIndex].source}
        </Text>
      </View>
    ) : null;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
          style={styles.albumCover}
          source={{
            uri:
              "http://www.archive.org/download/LibrivoxCdCoverArt8/hamlet_1104.jpg",
          }}
        />
        <View style={styles.controls}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.control}
            onPress={this.handlePreviousTrack}
          >
            <Ionicons name="arrow-back-circle-outline" size={48} color="#444" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.control}
            onPress={this.handlePlayPause}
          >
            {this.state.isPlaying ? (
              <Ionicons name="ios-pause" size={48} color="#444" />
            ) : (
              <Ionicons name="ios-play-circle" size={48} color="#444" />
            )}
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.control}
            onPress={this.handleNextTrack}
          >
            <Ionicons
              name="arrow-forward-circle-outline"
              size={48}
              color="#444"
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        {this.renderFileInfo()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#aaa",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  albumCover: {
    width: 250,
    height: 250,
  },
  trackInfo: {
    padding: 40,
    backgroundColor: "#aaa",
  },
  trackInfoText: {
    textAlign: "center",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    color: "#550088",
  },
  largeText: {
    fontSize: 22,
  },
  smallText: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  control: {
    margin: 20,
  },
  controls: {
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have it you are just missing one conceptual difference between the class and functional components. Namely how props are used inside the component ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)).

With a simple functional component, it is simply that, a function, and all the props are accessible *anywhere* in the component. But with a class component the props are bound to the class [instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS#constructors_and_object_instances) via `this.props`.

So now looking at your code, you are creating a local variable `cancionesPlaylist` inside of the class constructor but that variable is scoped only to within the constructor function [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block).

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  const cancionesPlaylist = props.cancionesPlaylist;
  console.log(cancionesPlaylist);
}
```

So when you try to access that local variable anywhere in your class you are actually referencing a likely nonexistent (i.e. `undefined`) global variable named `cancionesPlaylist`. What you need to do instead is just access the props on the class instance via `this.props.cancionesPlaylist`. You have access to [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) (aka the component/class instance) anywhere inside the class component, but it may not always be the same  see [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-this-gotchas/) for some general gotchas not specific to react.

Altogether with a little cleanup...

```js
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, View, Image } from "react-native";
import { Title, Text } from "react-native-paper";
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";
import { Button } from "../components/Button";
import { Audio, Video } from "expo-av";
import firebase from "../utils/firebase";
import "firebase/firestore";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

export default function ReproductorAudio(props) {
  const { route } = props;
  const { canciones } = route.params;
  const cancionesPlaylist = canciones;

  return <ReproductorMusica cancionesPlaylist={cancionesPlaylist} />;
}

class ReproductorMusica extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isPlaying: false,
    playbackInstance: null,
    currentIndex: 0,
    volume: 1.0,
    isBuffering: false,
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
        allowsRecordingIOS: false,
        interruptionModeIOS: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_IOS_DO_NOT_MIX,
        playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
        interruptionModeAndroid: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_ANDROID_DUCK_OTHERS,
        shouldDuckAndroid: true,
        staysActiveInBackground: true,
        playThroughEarpieceAndroid: true,
      });

      this.loadAudio();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  async loadAudio() {
    const { currentIndex, isPlaying, volume } = this.state;

    try {
      const playbackInstance = new Audio.Sound();
      const source = {
        uri: this.props.cancionesPlaylist[currentIndex].uri,
      };

      const status = {
        shouldPlay: isPlaying,
        volume,
      };

      playbackInstance.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(this.onPlaybackStatusUpdate);
      await playbackInstance.loadAsync(source, status, false);
      this.setState({ playbackInstance });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  onPlaybackStatusUpdate = (status) => {
    this.setState({
      isBuffering: status.isBuffering,
    });
  };

  handlePlayPause = async () => {
    const { isPlaying, playbackInstance } = this.state;
    isPlaying
      ? await playbackInstance.pauseAsync()
      : await playbackInstance.playAsync();

    this.setState({
      isPlaying: !isPlaying,
    });
  };

  handlePreviousTrack = async () => {
    let { playbackInstance, currentIndex } = this.state;
    if (playbackInstance) {
      await playbackInstance.unloadAsync();
      currentIndex < this.props.cancionesPlaylist.length - 1
        ? (currentIndex -= 1)
        : (currentIndex = 0);
      this.setState({
        currentIndex,
      });
      this.loadAudio();
    }
  };

  handleNextTrack = async () => {
    let { playbackInstance, currentIndex } = this.state;
    if (playbackInstance) {
      await playbackInstance.unloadAsync();
      currentIndex < this.props.cancionesPlaylist.length - 1
        ? (currentIndex += 1)
        : (currentIndex = 0);
      this.setState({
        currentIndex,
      });
      this.loadAudio();
    }
  };

  renderFileInfo() {
    const { playbackInstance, currentIndex } = this.state;
    return playbackInstance ? (
      <View style={styles.trackInfo}>
        <Text style={[styles.trackInfoText, styles.largeText]}>
          {this.props.cancionesPlaylist[currentIndex].name}
        </Text>
        <Text style={[styles.trackInfoText, styles.smallText]}>
          {this.props.cancionesPlaylist[currentIndex].author}
        </Text>
        <Text style={[styles.trackInfoText, styles.smallText]}>
          {this.props.cancionesPlaylist[currentIndex].source}
        </Text>
      </View>
    ) : null;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
          style={styles.albumCover}
          source={{
            uri:
              "http://www.archive.org/download/LibrivoxCdCoverArt8/hamlet_1104.jpg",
          }}
        />
        <View style={styles.controls}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.control}
            onPress={this.handlePreviousTrack}
          >
            <Ionicons name="arrow-back-circle-outline" size={48} color="#444" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.control}
            onPress={this.handlePlayPause}
          >
            {this.state.isPlaying ? (
              <Ionicons name="ios-pause" size={48} color="#444" />
            ) : (
              <Ionicons name="ios-play-circle" size={48} color="#444" />
            )}
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.control}
            onPress={this.handleNextTrack}
          >
            <Ionicons
              name="arrow-forward-circle-outline"
              size={48}
              color="#444"
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        {this.renderFileInfo()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#aaa",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  albumCover: {
    width: 250,
    height: 250,
  },
  trackInfo: {
    padding: 40,
    backgroundColor: "#aaa",
  },
  trackInfoText: {
    textAlign: "center",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    color: "#550088",
  },
  largeText: {
    fontSize: 22,
  },
  smallText: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  control: {
    margin: 20,
  },
  controls: {
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
});
```

> Removed the `constructor` as it was not needed and changed global variable lookup of `cancionesPlaylist` to prop lookup on class via `this.props.cancionesPlaylist`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly, i'm new using React-native and i'm so happy to learn this. You are a rockstar, again thank you so much!